# Can I use a transimpedance amplifier using current through a resistor?

Tags: current, voltage-source

I'm designing a lab exercise for 1st year circuits students.  They learn about current controlled voltage sources, but we never show them one.  I know that transimpedance amplifiers are used for this purpose, but I've only seen them used with devices that *produce* current, like a photodiode.

I'd like to have them choose a resistor and a voltage to generate a current through that resistor.  I want to tell them that the gain of the CCVS is X, and they are required to choose their resistor and voltage so that the output voltage of the CCVS is Y.

a) Can a transimpedance amplifier be used in this way?

b) If not, is there anything that can?

Comment: It sounds like you just re-invented the op-amp inverting voltage amplifier.

Comment: Isn't a shunt resistor + a differential amplifier good enough as a current controlled voltage source? Much easier to understand and might be interesting for the students to make something that is commonly used. Or maybe it doesn't count as "current controlled" since you're using the shunt to convert it to a voltage...

Comment: @Harry Svennson: exactly! But shunt + INA is much more  complicated to implement than a simple inverting OpAmp and the problem is that people often don't understand that what is generally meant by CCVS requires more than just some voltage source that is controlled by a current.

Comment: @Curd - although it's true that general CCVS's might be a lot more complex than what I need, honestly, I just need a simple demonstration for a first year lab.

Comment: @Michael Stachowsky: I understand; but I think you should mention the limitation, i.e. the fact that it is a special case that is good for many practical cases but different from what is understood by CCVS in circuit theory. Otherwise they really might run into trouble...

Comment: Fair point, well said

Comment: You may be over-reaching 1st-yr curriculum. Consider that an example you build can be over-driven into non-linearity. Avoid any circuits that need biasing - AC signals riding on DC bias is a concept *very difficult* for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain ordinary opamp configured as an inverting gain stage sounds exactly what you are looking for because, that is exactly how they work when fed with a voltage source in series with a resistor. Basically, a transimpedance amplifier is a subset of an opamp inverting amplifier.

You might also be interested in looking up the term virtual earth (as applied to an opamp).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.  I didn't realize that since I usually do my op-amp gains as $\frac{-R1}{Rf}$ and don't really notice that the actual output is $V_o = -i_{in}R1$

Answer (score 1):

- Answer to (a):
  In many (most) cases: yes; in general: No.
- Answer to (b):
  Yes, e.g. an instrumentation amplifier across a small (infinitesimal) shunt resistor

Note that **in general** a CCVS (or CCCS or VCVS or VCCS) has the controlling side (=input) completely insulated from the current (or voltage) source side (=output).

In general the controlling side and source side do not have to work with respect to same reference node (GND). 
I.e. the term CCVS often means more than just **a** voltage source that is controlled by a current.

Your proposed circuit is in fact a voltage spource that is controlled by a current, but it is **a special case** of CCVS in so far as it requires that the controlling current input is at the same potential as the reference potential (=GND) of the output voltage.
A CCVS in general does not have that limitation.

So if you sell your students a transimpendance amplifier as VCCS without restrictions they get a wrong impression what is meant by the term CCVS in circuit theory. At least you should mention the difference of the special implementation in contrast to the general theoretical idea of a CCVS.

BTW: you wrote "They learn about current controlled voltage sources, but we never show them one."
I think that's the case because such a general CCVS is quite difficult to implement (e.g. as instrumentation amplifier across a very (infinitesimal) small shunt resistor) and in praxis rarely needed; but very useful for theory.

Answer (score 0):

RCA introduced the voltage-in current-out amplifier, the CA3080 (single) and CA3060 (triple) approx. 1972. As long as the external bias-set-current pin caused IoutMax to exceed the max load current, the behavior was nearly the same as voltage-in voltage-out OpAmp.

I used the CA3060 (triple) as clocked sampler for syncro and resolver digitization.